# Will I have any issues installing a Hard Drive with another OS, on my computer

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, windows-10, operating-systems

My computer is running Windows 10, and I would like to plug my 1TB 7200rpm HD from my old computer into this as additional storage.

This other HD has windows 8.1 installed on it.

Will I have any issues if I plug this in my computer and boot it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be. Depends on the HDD cable sequence, and the BOOT sequence of your CMOS settings.
Just make sure it boots up with the win10 HDD, then it's ok, nothing will change except more partitions show up.

Tips:

- When you plug the second HDD, use sata(or ide) port with high number. (i.e. win10 hdd with sata0/sata1, 1T hdd use sata2/sata3 or more).
- When the computer powers on, use PAUSE key to pause booting, and ENTER key to continue, be aware the messages on the bottom of the screen. You can press DEL to enter CMOS settings to check the boot sequence.